# Change color of amsthm environment

Tags: amsthm

I have defined a new environment called `sltn` and want the text `Solution` to be green. The text working fine but the `.` after `Solution` also needs to be blue but I couldn't find any way to do that.

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newenvironment{sltn} {\begin{proof}[\bfseries \textcolor{green}{Solution}]} {\end{proof}} 

\begin{document}
    \begin{sltn}
        A solution.  
    \end{sltn}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The `thmtools` package cooperates with `amsthm` and provides efficient tools to customise theorem declarations and theorem styles:

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\declaretheoremstyle[%
spaceabove=6pt, spacebelow=6pt,
headfont=\normalfont\bfseries\color{green}, headindent=\parindent,
notefont=\mdseries, notebraces={(}{)},
bodyfont=\normalfont,
postheadspace=0.5em]%
{sol}

\declaretheorem[name=Solution, numbered=no, style=sol]{sltn}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[47]
    \begin{sltn}
        A very short solution.
    \end{sltn}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`Solution.` instead of `Solution`

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newenvironment{sltn} {
\begin{proof}[\bfseries \textcolor{green}{Solution.}]
}{\end{proof}} 

\begin{document}
    \begin{sltn}
        A solution.  
    \end{sltn}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a new theorem style with the formatting and punctuation you want.

This variant creates the unnumbered proof environment `sltn*` and the numbered environment `sltn`, which would give you “Solution 1.”

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\newtheoremstyle{solution}%
  {3pt}% Space above
  {3pt}% Space below
  {}% Body font
  {}% Indent amount
  {\bfseries\color{green}}% Theorem head font
  {\textcolor{blue}{.}}% Punctuation after theorem head
  {.5em}% Space after theorem head
  {}% Theorem head spec
\theoremstyle{solution}
\newtheorem{sltn}{Solution}
\newtheorem*{sltn*}{Solution}

\begin{document}
    \begin{sltn*}
        A solution.  
    \end{sltn*}
\end{document}
```

[image: A sample.]

See [the `amsthm` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amscls/doc/amsthdoc.pdf#section.4) if you need more details.

Note that the original code sample you posted actually selects bold small caps, which were not displaying only because the default bold font does not contain small caps.  If you genuinely wanted them, add `\scshape` to `\bfseries` and `\color`.